# How to control changeset priority in tfs for automatic patches?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

in our company we use tfs for source control of sql database version,when developers change the database they generate Equivalent script and put it in sql tfs project and checked in it with related workItem.after build we generate patch with this script for clients,but before pacth we need to some one decide on priority of checked in script,now i want to this decition become automatic and my question is how could specified priority in the moment of check in?
Sorry for my bad english,if you want more informationn to answer let me know.thanks.

Comment: You want to specify a value during check-in time? Do you know Check-in notes? Do you think it could be enough for you ? You can customize Check-in notes and add the field you want. Then viewing the field value later on when you display the detail of a changeset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by priority of checked in script?  What is this priority value used for?

Comment: I think he needs to record what order the patch scripts must be executed in.

Comment: yes,that is true,I want to record what order the patch scripts must be executed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version handling of databases seems to be a never-ending problem. At a previous client, we gave the databases version properties, and then stored patch scripts in folders for each version, e.g. "Patches/2.0.10", "Patches/2.1.0". The patch scripts could then be executed in the same order as they were checked in (creation date).

Upon release, we ended up generating a complete patch script consisting of all those separate patches merged together (since the patches often affected the same data, they could be optimized) along with a new version number, allowing us to record what version any given databes instance had.

Comment: i dont know @tbergstedt,the creation date for edited script will be changed or i must check another properties for edited scripts?

Comment: `CreationTime` will never change, `LastWriteTime` will when the file is edited.

Comment: thank you @tbergstedt for response.when you check out some files,after check in ,i think the lastWriteTime for all them must be the same,is that true?

Comment: should i tell to every developer to check in each changes individually?

Comment: Yes, `LastWriteTime` may become the same for several files if checked in simultaneously, so it's not an option to use that. You must find a way to get the original order. 1) Powershell `gci | sort CreationTime`. 2) Require the files named with their order, i.e "01-Script1.sql","02-Script2.sql" (a rather ugly and error-prone solution, I know). 3) Have the developers maintain a separate script in the same folder that is used to execute the patch scripts in the correct order.

Comment: I know this is not what you originally asked for, but that's because there is not way to maintain such an order using Work Items that I know of. Not without some (rather advanced) server-side programming that could update a bunch of WI's upon the event of creating/editing another WI.